# How do I group by one element and find the average of another in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, mean

I am working on a project comparing the age of wine to it's score and want to make a line chart with age on the X axis and average score for each age on the Y. I have an array of objects each containing two elements, age and score and want to group by each age and find the average score for that age.

I have a CSV file created by doing a request from Global Wine Score that has vintage, review date, score etc. In python, I created a column for age by subtracting the review year from the vintage. In Javascript I created a new array doing this:

```
    var newArr = countryFilter.map(function(elem) {
            return {
                age: elem.wine_age,
                score: elem.score
            };
        });
```

here is what my array looks like:

```
0: Object { age: "116", score: "98.51" }

​​​​
age: "116"

​​​​
score: "98.51"

​​​
​​​
1: Object { age: "113", score: "84.46" }

​​​​
age: "113"

​​​​
score: "84.46"

length: 23258
```

I tried this, but any object with more than 1 unique score yields NAN.

```
 const reduced = newArr.reduce(function(m, d){
        if(!m[d.age]){
          m[d.age] = {...d, count: 1};
          return m;
        }
        m[d.age].score += d.score;
        m[d.age].count += 1;
        return m;
     },{});

     const result = Object.keys(reduced).map(function(k){
         const item  = reduced[k];
         return {
             wine_age: item.age,
             score: item.score/item.count,
         }
     })

     console.log(result);
```

How would I go about finding the average wine score per wine age?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the objects in sub-arrays by age, then reduce the sub-arrays into single objects with the average score:

```js
const input = [
  { age: "113", score: "84.46" },
  { age: "113", score: "88.23" },
  { age: "112", score: "84.46" },
  { age: "113", score: "10.58" },
];

const result = input
  .sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age)
  .reduce(
    (acc, cur, i, { [i - 1]: last }) =>
      cur.age === last?.age
        ? Object.assign([...acc], {
            [acc.length - 1]: [...acc[acc.length - 1], cur],
          })
        : [...acc, [cur]],
    []
  )
  .map((x) => ({
    age: x[0].age,
    score: x.reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b.score), 0) / x.length,
  }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi @Guerric P! Nice answer. Just for learning purposes, would you explain what does the first `reduce` method do? I'm a bit confused and would like to understand the answer completely. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first reduce purpose is to create an array of arrays. Each array contains only the objects with a specific age. It considers that the array is already sorted by age, and compares the current item's age with the previous one. If i'ts the same age, the object is being added to the last sub-array, otherwise it is added to a new sub-array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get it. You'll end up with an object of age:average pairs:

```
let grps={} 
data.forEach(g => grps.hasOwnProperty(g.age)? // first we set up the age -> array of scores object
     grps[g.age].push(+g.score) : grps[g.age] = [+g.score]),
 avgs = Object.assign(...Object.entries(grps) // then we take that object and calculate the avg based on the total score tally / number of scores
     .map(g=>({[g[0]]:
     (g[1].reduce((b,a)=> b+a)/grps[g[0]].length).toFixed(2)}))) // reduce is a perfect vehicle for tallying up arrays of numbers.
```

```js
let data = [
{ age: "113", score: "84.46" },
  { age: "113", score: "88.23" },
  { age: "112", score: "84.46" },
  { age: "113", score: "10.58" },
]
let grps={}, s = data.forEach(g=>grps.hasOwnProperty(g.age)?grps[g.age].push(+g.score) : grps[g.age] = [+g.score]), avgs = Object.assign(...Object.entries(grps).map(g=>({[g[0]]:(g[1].reduce((b,a)=> b+a)/grps[g[0]].length).toFixed(2)})))
console.log(avgs)
```

Comment: @GuerricP - that is no longer true, answer revised. Thanks for calling it out, tho. It seemed to make sense to me at the time, but was absolutely the wrong method